# How can I add embed objects in emails?

Tags: mdriven

I want to embed images in my email content, for example logo. Normally in C# I add LinkedResource and refer to contentId in my email template. How can I do this in MDriven?

Answer (score 1):

Is the image data or static?
Do you want the image to be included or referenced?

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,base64-data-string here" />
```

Your byte array to base64 and like above.

Updated with new info that MDrivenServer now also support inline disposition of images added as attachments with contentid : https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Emailing_from_an_app_using_MDrivenServer

Comment: In the email template the image look like this <img src="cid:Emaillogo" alt="Logo" />.  To add the image  in C# the 

 AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgHtml.Body, null, "text/html");
string logopath = GetGlobalCompanyfilePath(aForetag) + HTML_MAIL_LOGO_NAME;
if (File.Exists(logopath))
 { LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(logopat
   res.ContentLink = new Uri(logopath);
    res.ContentId = "Emaillogo";
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
                    }
       msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

Comment: I will test the base64 solution

Comment: The  <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/png;base64,{{%emaillogo%}}"/> generates an error.

Comment: Did new test and the base64 is there but image is broken, I use BlobToBase64.

Comment: It works only when using opendocumentreportshow. When trying to send as email body it do not work. Get error log:
2020-05-27 14:48:03,164 [113] ERROR AppCompleteGeneric.admin.LogUsage -
EXCEPTION:
bughuntinfo internaleval:83 es seems fineAsByteArray: Error producing Open document report bughuntinfo internaleval:83 es seems fineValue cannot be null. Parameter name: inArray
vBody := self.Order.opendocumentreportasblob(Order.Viewmodels.HtmlOrderConfirmation ).asString

Comment: src="data:image/png;base64,{{%emaillogo%}}"/ will end up as src="data:image/png;base64,{{BASE64data==}}"/  -> the {{ }} destroys your data.

Use src="data:image/png;base64,%emaillogo%"

Comment: Now it work great, thanks MDriven for absolutely terrific support!